# it shows SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing whenever i run the code

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

```
from sense_hat import SenseHat
from time import sleep, strftime

sense = SenseHat()

# ------------------------------------------------
# DATA
# ------------------------------------------------

# Colours
colours = {

  'r' : [255, 0, 0],
  # Add orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet here
  'o' : [255, 125, 0],
  'y' : [255, 255, 0],
  'g' : [0, 255, 0],
  'b' : [0, 0, 255],
  'i' : [75, 0, 130],
  'v' : [51, 2, 170],
  'n' : [135, 80, 22],
  'w' : [255, 255, 255],
  'e' : [0, 0, 0]  # e stands for empty/black

}

# Pictures
with open("pictures.txt", "r") as f:
  all_pics = f.readlines()
# ------------------------------------------------
# FUNCTIONS
# ------------------------------------------------
# Display a given picture string on the sense HAT
# ------------------------------------------------
def display_pic(pic_string):

  # Get rid of newline and split the line into a list
  pic_string = pic_string.strip("\n")
  pic_string = pic_string.split(",")

  # Look up each letter in the dictionary of colours and add it to the list
  pic_list = []
  for letter in pic_string:
      pic_list.append(colours[letter])

  # Display the pixel colours from the file
  sense.set_pixels(pic_list)



# ------------------------------------------------
# MAIN PROGRAM
# ------------------------------------------------
sense.clear()
display_pic(all_pics[7]



it show this-----> SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

this code is to show images on a raspberry pi sense HAT please tell me to solve this problem. thank you n how i can edit the code . i followed the instructions on the raspberry pi website. i am making a advent calendar using sense HAT i expected it to make the sense HAT show pictures.

Comment: Missing a closing `)` after `display_pic(all_pics[7]`

Answer (score 0):

add a ) to the last line

display_pic(all_pics[7]   )